# Get table list in Joomla with Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, joomla3.0

1#. Any-buddy can explain me following sqlite things in joomla

```
$query->select('name')
      ->from('sqlite_master')     // sqlite_master ??
      ->where('type = :type')     // :type??
      ->bind(':type', 'table')     // purpose of bind  ??
      ->order('name');
```

2#. Actual query look like

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = :type
ORDER BY name
```

but its not working. :-(
When I have changed where clause  `WHERE type = 'table'` then it will work properly.

Comment: Ok, Got the answer by debugging. :-) Might be its a bug in joomla. Just try to confirm it. Any-buddy is getting same issue?? (let me debugging again :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug in Joomla So query is not proper populated. 
[(Issue filed)](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/1995)